# How to make observable to continue emiting values even if error was thrown

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Error is thrown and replaced. But then execution is ended. How to make observable to emit 10 elements?

```
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx')

Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .map((i) => {
    if (i === 2) throw(new Error('omg'))
    return i
  })
  .take(10)
  .catch((err) => {
    return Rx.Observable.of('ok, we caught an error, but we don\'t want to exit')
  })
  .do(console.log, console.error)
  .subscribe()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could supply a function that handles the errors and returns an observable. You'll need to use `flatMap` instead since you'll be using a higher order function.

```
function handleError(cb){
    return (val) => {
        try{
            return Rx.Observable.of(cb(val));
        }catch(err){
            console.error(`${err}`);
            return Rx.Observable.empty();
        }
    }
}

Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
    .flatMap(handleError(i => {
        if (i === 2) throw(new Error('omg'))
        return i;
    }))
    .take(10)
    .do(console.log)
    .subscribe()

// emits
// 0
// 1
// "Error: omg"
// 3
// 4
// 5
// 6
// 7
// 8
// 9
// 10
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/lifacedade/1/edit?js,console)

Another example that doesn't quite fit your example code but is worth mentioning, the lead developer of RxJS, Ben Lesh, touched on this issue in a post called *[On The Subject Of Subjects (in RxJS)](https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93#.pcmlgg1mx)*. There's a section halfway through called "Gotchas in RxJS."

> [...] Since Rx observables do not “trap” errors, we can run into some
>   strange behavior here. Error “trapping” is a behavior I myself have
>   derided Promises for implementing, but in multicast scenarios it may
>   be the right move. What I mean when I say Rx observable does not
>   “trap” errors is basically that when an error percolates to the end of
>   the observer chain, if the error is unhandled, it will be re-thrown.

Here is one code example from that section (the simplest but not most performant):

```
const source$ = Observable.interval(1000)
  .share()
  .observeOn(Rx.Scheduler.asap); // magic here
const mapped$ = source$.map(x => {
  if (x === 1) {
    throw new Error('oops');
  }
  return x;
});
source$.subscribe(x => console.log('A', x));
mapped$.subscribe(x => console.log('B', x));
source$.subscribe(x => console.log('C', x));
// "A" 0
// "B" 0
// "C" 0
// "A" 1
// Uncaught Error: "oops"
// "C" 1
// "A" 2
// "C" 2 
// "A" 3
// "C" 3
// ... etc
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/gocuqefeta/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no RxJS guru, but I'd like to try to answer this.

Throwing an error with RxJS terminates the observable.  As a result, you cannot resume it, but can only attempt to retry/repeat the observable.

If you do not want to replay the error and must only take the original 10 elements, then you could `return null` instead of `throw new Error` and just `filter(x => x)` before you `take(10)`.

Otherwise, you can use `retryWhen` to repeat the observable on error.  Note that this would take the 2 items, fail, and then it would start over repeating on 0, 1, ...  It caps out after 2 fails, but still only takes 10 items.

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .map((i) => {
    if (i === 2) throw(new Error('omg'))
    return i
  })
  .retryWhen((errors) => errors.scan(
    (errorCount, err) => {
        if(errorCount >= 2) {
            throw err;
        }

        return errorCount + 1;
    }, 0)
  )
  .take(10)
  .catch((err) => {
    return Rx.Observable.of('ok, we caught an error, but we don\'t want to exit')
  })
  .subscribe((x) => console.log('result', x))
```

You can also use `repeat` to just keep repeating whenever the observable finishes.  This is likely not what you want, but I wanted to show it to you as an option anyway.  You will need to pay attention to where you place take and it also "counts" the emitted catch observable.

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .map((i) => {
    if (i === 2) throw(new Error('omg'))
    return i
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    return Rx.Observable.of('ok, we caught an error, but we don\'t want to exit')
  })
  .repeat()
  .take(10)
  .subscribe((x) => console.log('result', x))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Observable contract is `OnNext*(OnError|OnCompleted)+`.

Once the sequence ends, downstream operators must unsubscribe. You can only resubscribe to the pipeline. If your observable is cold, then you can use the `retry` operator to resubscribe.

```
observable
.retry()
.take(10)
.subscribe()
```